# Specialized template constructors not seen as constructors

Tags: c++, templates

This code:

```
constexpr uint32_t ticksPerSecond = 100000;

struct ticks {
    uint32_t count;
    template<typename integer>
    constexpr explicit ticks(integer c) : count(c) { }
    explicit inline operator float() {
        return count / (float) ticksPerSecond;
    }
};

template<>
constexpr explicit ticks::ticks<float>(float s) : count(s * ticksPerSecond) { }
```

Gives me the error:

```
timer.hpp:(last line of snippet):
error: only declarations of constructors can be 'explicit'
```

Surely `ticks::ticks` *is* the constructor?

Comment: perhaps you should remove the `constexpr` keyword?

Comment: Once you have solved your issue and it compiles, consider changing the code. Function template specializations are not usually the best idea. You should prefer a non-templated overload.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Are you saying I can just declare a non-template version of the constructor, and it will take priority over the template version?

Comment: @Eric: yes, you can declare a non-template constructor that takes a `float` and it will take precedence in all contexts *except* when the user explicitly requests the template version by providing the template argument.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: But you can't explicitly request the template version of a _constructor_, can you? `ticks<float>(2.5)` would try to instantiate the template _class_ `ticks<float>`, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Eric: Correct, I was talking in general for general member functions, not templates. In the case of constructors the template argument cannot be explicitly set, so the plain overload will always be picked up.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear, you can only use `explicit` in **declarations** (not in definitions). Just remove that keyword from the specialization:

```
template<>
constexpr ticks::ticks<float>(float s) : count(s * ticksPerSecond) { }
```

Comment: Darn, I was reading it as _"only declarations of __constructors__"_, not _"only __declarations__ of constructors"_

Comment: You should read that as '**only declarations of constructors**' ;-)